# How to set network access to only a particular service/directory in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, lamp

I am using xampp in a local system, connected to a network. Now I need to make only a particular service, say limesurvey or wordpress, installed on my system accessible across the entire network. But I don't want the xampp landing page or phpmyadmin to be accessible to others.

How can this be achieved ?

Right now entire `xampp` is accessible to anyone, including `phpmyadmin`.

In file `httpd-xampp.conf`

Right now I am using the following settings

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
   #Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
            fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
            fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

If instead I can set some password for default `xampp` page or `phpmyadmin`, that also will work for me, as the server doesn't have any other services.

Answer (score 1):

Step 5 might help you. Please go through the following Tutorial completely.

http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/installing-a-local-server/installing-xampp/

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Comment: This doesnt help, because, after running thesecurity, for accessing any page, it is asked to put password